# ActionBar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) vs setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true). What's the difference?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The title is pretty much self explanatory. What are the exact differences? I'll post sample code below.

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation is pretty much self explanatory.

[`ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29) specifies whether or not the Home button is shown.

[`ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29) specifies whether or not the Home button has the arrow used for [Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) next to it.

Comment: But isn't the home button at the bottom?

Comment: This is just wrong. `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` will show the home icon. As this use is deprecated, it will not show anything unless you set an icon via the `setIcon()` function on the action bar

Comment: @Boy I can see no indication that it is (or ever was considered as) deprecated. Please provide some proof for this adventurous statement.

Comment: I have no idea where I came up with the idea that it was officially deprecated, it's been almost a year ;) But I guess I used that word because we do no longer show icons on that location, only a arrow, which is being set by setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()